# Schedule Windows Task with Managed Service Account on DC

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, managed-service-accounts

I have downloaded a script from TechNet and i am scheduling this with the MSA(Manage Service Account) on a DC. I get the error

**Task Scheduler launched "{!@#!#!@#}"  instance of task "\TasknamE"  for user "MSA$" .**

**Task Scheduler failed to start "\TasknamE" task for user "domain\MSA$". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943785.**

The script works well with a domain account.

I have added a user to **Logon as a Batch** - Nogo
added user to Domain Admin group - Nogo

it'll be great if you could support this!!!!

Comment: Here you can find a few workarounds to fix the problem, write which one was helpful. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/68019b24-78a5-4db0-a150-ada921930924/task-scheduler-failed-to-start-additional-data-error-value-2147943785?forum=winservergen

Comment: I have tried most of these, but nogo!!!!
local policies, group policies, default DC policy - added to logon as batch

Comment: Adding user to the Domain Administrator group helped me a few months ago, but right now I don't even know what to add, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I turned out that I needed to change the default domain controller group policy to allow the gmsa account to logon as a service.